# How to insert to Postgresql geometry column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a WKT data which looks like so:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(
POINT(-1763555.1165955865 310640.0829509564),
POINT(-1421117.229877997 -300856.1433304538)
)
```

The default projection is 'EPSG:3857'. In postgresql I created a parent table whith generic geometry column and several child tables with columns of specific geometry type. The schema looks like so:

```
# parent table with generic geometry column "geom"
CREATE TABLE "public"."layer_261_" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('layer_261__id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"feature_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"feature_name" varchar(200),
"feature_type" varchar(50),
"geom" "public"."geometry",
"object_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"row_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
) 
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_" ADD CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 3857);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_" ADD CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");

# child table which is supposed to contain only POINT data type
CREATE TABLE "public"."layer_261_points" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('layer_261__id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"feature_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"feature_name" varchar(200),
"feature_type" varchar(50),
"geom" "public"."geometry",
"object_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"row_id" int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
INHERITS ("public"."layer_261_") 
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_points" ADD CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_points" ADD CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'POINT'::text);
ALTER TABLE "public"."layer_261_points" ADD CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 3857);
```

So, how can I insert my data (two points to the database)? For example, I'm not sure whether I should convert points' coordinates to lat-lon. And besides, I'm not sure whether I should insert GEOMETRYCOLLECTION or all points one by one.

**EDIT**

I've just tried to execute a query with a real data point:

```
INSERT INTO layer_261_ (geom) VALUES (ST_Point(105177.3509204, -85609.471679397))
```

But as a result I got this error message:

> new row for relation "layer_261_" violates check constraint
>   "enforce_srid_geom"

Does anybody know how to fix it?

**EDIT**

This query leads to the very same error message:

```
INSERT INTO layer_261_ (geom) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(105177.3509204, -85609.471679397), 
4326))
```

Comment: You should use SRID 3857.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only insert the WKT into the parent table because the point table won't accept a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."layer_261_" ("geom", <other columns>)
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(<your WKT>, 3857), <other values>);
```

Once you have the data in the parent table you can easily convert from the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` to separate `POINT`s using `ST_Dump()` and insert those in the point table:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."layer_261_points" ("geom", <other columns>)
  SELECT p.geom, <other columns>
  FROM "public"."layer_261_" m, ST_Dump("geom") p
  WHERE ...;
```

You can of course also forget about the first step and do `ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText(<your WKT>, 3857))` in the second step but that is less intuitive and more prone to errors.

Note that `ST_Dump()` is a [table function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) so it should be used in a `FROM` clause. It can then use columns from tables specified before the function.

The error you were getting from using `ST_Point()` is because you the geometry has a NULL SRID. You should set that explicitly with `ST_SetSRID()` (one of my great annoyances with PostGIS...).

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it in a second!

Comment: Can you, please, provide some real data instead of `<your WKT>`. I'm not sure how it should look like in the context of my data

Comment: You just replace `<your WKT>` with the string that you have. WKT is just a string format, easy to work with but not efficient, hence why it is converted.

Comment: Oh, I managed to insert. I've just replaced 4326 with 3857, like you suggested. But what is interesting is that data was added to the parent table. Is it ok? I thought parent table is just an abstract one.

Comment: When you insert into the parent table, the data is only visible there. Inversely, when you insert into the child table, you can see the data in the inherited column of the parent. However, you repeat all columns in the child table, effectively blocking that for the parent table. Your point table should **only** have the `geom` column, other columns are then inherited from the parent table.

Comment: Thank you! Now I've got it!